# What production grade linux has MySQL 5.5?

Tags: linux, mysql5.5

I want production grade linux with LTS, long term support, that has MySQL 5.5. I.e. no third party repositories, no downloading binaries from mysql.org. Are there any available now or soon?

The first I can find is April 2012 ...

Comment: whats wrong with using a current "production quality" OS and getting mysql from mysql.org?

Comment: Why box yourself into a corner like this? Even IF you find a production grade Linux with "LTS", you sure aren't going to get any help on the MySQL side.  Your best bet is to stick with a RedHat variant (e.g.: CentOs) - the Mysql.org RPM's install flawlessly

Comment: Had a problem not being able to source a what I thought was a standard lib with Amazon Linux - couldn't install perl DBD MySQL. So wanted to know if I could avoid sourcing anything myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 5 and 6 have a good repo available for the lastest mysql RPM's without needing to compile it. http://rpms.famillecollet.com/

enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure versioning, honestly your best bet is to install manually.

Additionally, you should consider Percona; it's a largely drop-in replacement for MySQL.  (We replaced MySQL on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS earlier this year, and have been very happy with it.)  there are some caveats to Percona pertaining to your existing tables, but that is your due diligence to do...